# Concerning converting variables, parseInt, and how to add/alter specific numbers in my output

Tags: java, loops

I'm writing a "MasterCardValidator" which reads the 16-digit string from the user, then will go through the Luhn's formula, which will then declare if the CC numbers entered are indeed from a valid MasterCard.

In line 20, I want to alter the output of this line: the numbers (5076802) that are printed out. I will use these numbers for some arithmetic (i.e. the Luhn formula), but I'm not at that step yet.

I've created a while loop that iterates through the necessary characters for the user's CC input (line 8) and prints the necessary numbers I need, right. But I can't seem to deal with these numbers how I would a regular integer?

I'm unsure if I should create a `for` loop, and then iterate through line 20 output, multiplying/mod'ing necessary numbers for Luhn's formula?

I've commented relevant line numbers:

```
System.out.print("Enter a card number for validation: ");
String CCnum = input.next();        // 8, using 2221008763790559

int i = 14;                         // 10

while (i <= 14 && i > 0) {          // 12
   int a = CCnum.charAt(i) - '0';   // 13, The nums needed from original CCnum string in line 8

   i -= 2;                          // 18 

   System.out.print(a + " ");       // 20,  Prints 5 0 7 6 8 0 2             
}
```

Comment: Why can't you deal with an `int` as a regular integer? I'm assuming you are talking about line 13; Or are you saying that you cannot deal with the contents of the string in line 8 as regular integers?

Comment: Why not apply your computation at the end of the while loop instead of printing the number out.

Comment: Are you asking how to pack the integer / concatenate the digits? Your multiply by 10 trick would work fine for that.

Comment: @smac89 Well, I think/thought I was struggling with the latter part of your question: I cannot deal with the contents in line 8 as regular integers. I think that's where I'm stumped at. But you're right, actually, I can?

Like I see that I can print `a * 2` and it will do just that for each number giving me: `10 0 14 12 16 0 4'. Which is on the right track. But now I want to create a loop to single out the numbers that are greater than 9...I'm taking in y'alls comments and testing while I read.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you just put all these numbers into an array to begin with. At the end if you want to print the array, you can use `java.util.Arrays.toString(myArray)` to convert the array to string

Comment: @Martin'sRun, I print periodically just to see what the input is after my tests, I'll take it out in the final test.

Comment: Are you actually trying to code the [Luhn Algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/luhn-algorithm/) with Java?